# Trying to hide image after remote javascript loads

Tags: jquery, image, hide

OK I have an issue I cant seem to find quite the right solution - I think I am close - using jquery, and I have this in the  tags:

```
<script type="tex/javascript">
$('#waitdiv').eq(1).ready(function() {
$("#loadingdiv").hide();
});

</script>
```

This is the relevant HTML code :

```
<div id="loadingdiv" ><img src="images/pleasewait.gif" />
<div id="waitdiv" >
<script type="text/javascript" id="privatelabel" src="**REMOTE URL WITH custom code that loads third party app"> </script>
 </div></div>
```

As you can probably see what I am trying to do, I want to display the please wait animated gif (or whatever image I put in place) , until the subsequent div is able to load (8 times of 10 it loads in a couple seconds, but sometimes it hangs for 10 to 30 seconds or more) , and then the "loading" image is hidden.

I thought I had it solved with some simple jquery, but evidently I have not yet mastered it.  I have yet to try it "the other way around" (That is, while waitdiv ready status is false, show() the image in question.. ) - but seems to me I want to wait til it loads and ready status is true.. ?

Ive tried several other solutions posted here (and other places) and just cannot seem to find anything that does quite what I need to do, or, the "solutions" do not work in my particular case..

I think I am just missing something simple - probably glaringly ovbvious to the experts here, but I am simply stuped at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use the [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method for jQuery.  Something like so:

```
$.getScript('yourcustomsource',function() { $("#loadingdiv").hide(); });
```

This loads and executes the script and once is loaded, it hides your loading image.

Comment: OK. well unless I am missing something - it isn't going to do what I need - I forgot to mention that the source actually displays content in the page - I had attempted getscript earlier, but could not make the callback work to display the results of the loaded application.
 Basically it (the app) essentially works sort of like an iframe, but without using iframes - I not only need to fetch the script, but also display the entire results of it (it is dynamic) in place of the loading image, once it is loaded.  It is a little complicated.. :) (Sort of like google maps, I guess)